# Angular routing not working within component

Tags: angular

I have 2 components and I want to go from the first to the second component when clicking on a `div`.

In the first component I did:

```
export class FirstComponent
{
    constructor(private router: Router)
    { }

    gotoLink(link: string)
    {
        console.log(link);
        this.router.navigate([link]);
    }
}
```

The `link` parameter is passed to component from the template and is something like `my/second/path`.

I created a second component and a module. The module looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { SecondComponent } from './second.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path     : 'my/second/path',
        component: SecondComponent 
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SecondComponent
    ],
    imports     : [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ],
    providers   : [ ]
})
export class SecondModule
{
}
```

This is the `app.module`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path        : 'private',
        loadChildren: './some/private/path/private.module#PrivateModule'
    },
    {
        path        : '**',
        redirectTo  : 'home'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports     : [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    ],
    bootstrap   : [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule
{
}
```

However, the routing is not working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with link string it should be like
  **/my/second/path**. it should always start with forward slash.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono it would be helpful to answer if you could post your AppModule code as well.

Comment: in your AppModule u have not declared route for SecondModule. If it would be similar as your private module then the path should be /private/my/second/path

Comment: Why does it have to be declared in 2 places?

Comment: you need to declare {
        path        : 'second',
        loadChildren: 'path-of-second-module#SecondModule'
    } in AppModule and then the path would be /second/my/second/path. otherwise how would Angular know which module to load.

Comment: The routing is working partially. The path changes. However I get a blank page.